# adding content to the bx content slider

Tags: html, css, slider, bxslider

I am currently trying to implement [THIS](http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls) very simple content slider however, I am starting to wonder whether or not it actually IS a content slider as I need to align a div centrally. My apologies, I posted the question accidentally too soon and it wasnt specific enough, what I need to do is align a div centrally with a h1 text line above it with a smaller h2 line of text below it can you help? Can somebody please show me? If it is not a genuine content slider can somebody show me how I can make it a content slider? Thank you.

My current code is below.

***My HTML code***

```
<body>

<ul class="bxslider">
<li style="background-image: url('http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/hillside.jpg');"></li>
<li style="background-image: url('http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/houses.jpg');"></li>
<li style="background-image: url('http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/hillside.jpg');"></li>
<li style="background-image: url('http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/houses.jpg');"></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

***My CSS code***

```
<style>
.bx-wrapper {
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
padding: 0;
*zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
max-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

 .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
border:  5px solid #fff;
left: -5px;
background: #fff;

/*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
-webkit-transform: translatez(0);
-moz-transform: translatez(0);
-ms-transform: translatez(0);
-o-transform: translatez(0);
transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
position: absolute;
bottom: -30px;
width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
min-height: 50px;
background: url(images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
text-align: center;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
color: #666;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
 }

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
background: #666;
text-indent: -9999px;
display: block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
margin: 0 5px;
outline: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
left: 10px;
background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
right: 10px;
background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -16px;
outline: 0;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
text-indent: -9999px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 10px;
height: 11px;
outline: 0;
background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 9px;
height: 11px;
outline: 0;
background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
text-align: left;
width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
right: 0;
width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: #666\9;
background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
color: #fff;
font-family: Arial;
display: block;
font-size: .85em;
padding: 10px; 
}

*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
body, html{
height: 100%;
}
.bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100% !important;
top:0;
left:0;
}
.bxslider, .bxslider li{
height: 100% !important;;
}
.bxslider li{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-size: cover;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
border: none !important;
}*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
body, html{
height: 100%;
}
.bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100% !important;
top:0;
left:0;
}
.bxslider, .bxslider li{
height: 100% !important;;
}
.bxslider li{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-size: cover;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
border: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: my apologies, I posted the question accidentally too soon and it wasnt specific enough, what I need to do is align a div centrally with a h1 text line above it with a smaller h2 line of text below it can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your content within `li` like that:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>more text</li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n7g8mk4/)

**Update 1.**

It doesn't matter which content you want to display just format it add proper styling and put it into `li` element.

Here you are your div with centred headers - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n7g8mk4/2/)

Comment: my apologies, I posted the question accidentally too soon and it wasnt specific enough, what I need to do is align a div centrally with a h1 text line above it with a smaller h2 line of text below it can you help?